# Why is my ECS task public IP not loading, if the logs say the service has started?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, ip-address, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to deploy a super simple containerized flask app to ECS. I know the image is `docker-compose`-able and building fine because I have it as part of a CodePipeline that's building, tagging and pushing the final docker image to ECR.

```
Build completed on Sat Feb 15 21:48:44 UTC 2020

[Container] 2020/02/15 21:48:44 Running command echo Pushing the Docker images...
Pushing the Docker images...

[Container] 2020/02/15 21:48:44 Running command docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
...
025f20c0831b: Pushed
98e916abdf11: Pushed
```

I should probably clarify at this point that the application works locally, and I've specified the `app.run()` host to `0.0.0.0`.

At this point I have an ECS Cluster

[image]

with a running task and public IP

[image]

and logs that indicate the app has started.

[image]

I have also modified the security group's inbound ports to include 5000 on `0.0.0.0`, `::/0`.

[image]

Theoretically this means you should be able to visit the port [3.80.1.115](http://3.80.1.115), but instead you should be seeing the standard, what did you just even type in response from your browser.

[image]

I'm just not sure what is happening anymore because I seem so close... the app is running without errors in ECS and everything is wonderful except the app is, well, inaccessible. Thoughts?

Comment: After I added inbound rule to VPC security group to allow the traffic, for me the public IP of the task started to be reachable from the Internet.

Answer (score 3):

My case is slightly different. I used the default network settings. The problem is that the default security group doesn't allow inbound traffic from the internet. To fix it:

1. Open the security group settings
2. Press "Edit inbound rules"
3. Add a rule with type "All traffic" (or "Custom TCP" if you want to whitelist a specific port) and source "Anywhere-IPv4"
4. Press "Save rules" and you're done

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should review the `networkMode` and `portMappings` settings for your ECS task definition.

In the security group, you're allowing traffic for the port `TCP/80`, but what I can read at your application logs (`Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/`) is that your app is running in a different port `TCP/5000`.

Here is an example for a Nginx task listening on por `TCP/80`:

```
{
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "nginx",
      "image": "nginx:latest",
      "memory": 256,
      "cpu": 256,
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration":{
            "logDriver":"awslogs",
            "options":{
               "awslogs-group":"awslogs-nginx-ecs",
               "awslogs-region":"us-east-1",
               "awslogs-stream-prefix":"ecs"
            }
      }
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "family": "nginx",
  "memory": "512",
  "cpu": "256"
}
```

You can see other examples [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-containers-task-definitions)

Comment: not entirely sure what you're getting at.. in the screenshot of inbound ports TCP 5000 is clearly indicated as an option, and also the same port the flask application is running on

Comment: and if http vs tcp was the issue you were getting at, i was following a tutorial on youtube [here (time linked)](https://youtu.be/-Vsuzi4OByY?t=1311) that has the exact same log and running on http://0.0.0.0:5000

Comment: I have setup a security group as what my  expose port on Dockerfile is set up, but the public IPTasks from the Service is still showed can't be reached.